# How to use lambda function in python

Tags: python, lambda

I was recently programming and I came across the lambda function. It seemed pretty interesting, but all the responses to how to use it and what it is were really confusing. Can someone put a simple explanation of when to use it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, anonymous function is a function that is defined without a name.

While normal functions are defined using the def keyword, in Python anonymous functions are defined using the lambda keyword.

Hence, anonymous functions are also called lambda functions.

EDIT: lambda functions *should* be anonymous, but they don't have to be anonymous, you can assign them.

EDIT2: The lambda operator or lambda function is a way to create small anonymous functions, i.e. functions without a name

Comment: Stack Overflow

Search…
 

1
Home
PUBLIC
Stack Overflow
Tags
Users
Jobs
Teams+Slack
Q&A for work
Learn More
 
How to use lambda function in python [duplicate]
Ask Question
up vote
-2

Comment: I am no understand your comment sir